# Why do optional arguments appear before positional arguments in the help output from argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

Code:

```py
import argparse
import sys
from fontbro import Font

def get_font_format(font_path, ignore_flavor):
    """
    Gets the font format: otf, ttf, woff, woff2.

    :param font_path: Path to the font file.
    :param ignore_flavor: If True, the original format without compression will be returned.
    :returns: The format.
    :rtype: str or None
    """
    font = Font(font_path)
    return font.get_format(ignore_flavor=ignore_flavor)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get the font format of a font file.')
    parser.add_argument('font_path', type=str, help='The path to the font file')
    parser.add_argument('--ignore_flavor', action='store_true', help='Return original format without compression if set to True')
    # Print help if no arguments supplied
    if len(sys.argv)==1:
        parser.print_help(sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # Get and print the font format
    format = get_font_format(args.font_path, args.ignore_flavor)
    print(format)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I run the script without any arguments I get help/usage:

```
usage: FontOpsGetFontFormat.py [-h] [--ignore_flavor] font_path

Get the font format of a font file.

positional arguments:
  font_path        The path to the font file

options:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --ignore_flavor  Return original format without compression if set to True
```

Why isn't the usage info formatted like this instead?

`usage: FontOpsGetFontFormat.py font_path [-h] [--ignore_flavor]`

From my limited understanding, positional arguments come first and others come after - is this incorrect?

Comment: Because that's the general UNIX convention. *Python's* function arguments have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Traditionally most UNIX commands take options before positional arguments, not the other way around, so that's how the usage is displayed. Taking options before positional arguments also has the benefit of allowing the `--` option to declare that all the following arguments are positional arguments, including those prefixed with dashes.

Comment: So this behavior is a result of following UNIX convention? It seems kind of odd to me but I guess I'll have to get used to it.

Comment: If you look at most other command line programs, they’ll mostly look like this, yes.

Comment: When initializing the parser you can provide a custom `usage` (along with the `description`) if you prefer to show you users a different order.  It won't make a difference in how the inputs are parsed.  `optionals` can be placed anywhere (with a few exceptions for variable `nargs` arguments).